# BIC-Lasso Shrinkage

Tags: r, lasso, glmnet, bic

I am currently reviewing the below paper and was wondering if it was possible to correctly implement the BIC equation for "BIC-LASSO Shrinkage". This doesn't appear to be the same as the typical BIC equation itself. I've been reviewing the below function ic.glmnet but just wanted to make sure the formula used here is correct for BIC-LASSO Shrinkage. Would it be possible to confirm that this code is the correct implementation in R?

https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/dflasso.pdf

https://github.com/gabrielrvsc/HDeconometrics/blob/master/R/ic.glmnet.R